# Building Edgelist in Python

Tags: python, network-analysis

I am working on a co-authorship network between COVID19 scholars and the data I got looks like below.[image] To build a network, I first need to convert it to an edgelist while assigning value to distinguish the effect of the main author and the co-authors.

Does anyone know how I can do this in Python?

Comment: Please share a sample of the data. Are you interested in any network analysis library in particular? Have you looked into how you would do this?

Comment: Hi yatu, you can click the hyperlink below to see what the data looks like, it is as simply as authors name in different colmumns since I drop other variables to just building a sample network at this stage.

Comment: the library I intend to use is NetworkX and therefore I need to have a edgelist at the first place

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe. Otherwise it is much harder to reproduce your problem. Just copy/paste it